# GAE standard environmentでのPub/Sub

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

GAEやPub/Subのドキュメントでは
GAEにてPub/Subを利用するのにフレキシブル環境でのドキュメントはありますが
スタンダード環境でのドキュメントがありません
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/tutorials

スタンダード環境にてPub/Subを使用したい場合はどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

スタンダード環境でも Pub/Sub は使用できます。ただし、GAEのスタンダード環境には、Cloud Pub/Sub Client Libraries が標準で入っていないので、アプリケーションコードに含める必要があります。アプリケーションコードに含める方法は、Pythonの場合であれば、以下のurlに説明があります。
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
また、API のライブラリーをコードに含めてしまえば、使い方はフレキシブル環境と違いはありません。

なお、スタンダード環境では、Pub/Sub とよく似た機能の Task Queue が使用できます。特に問題がなければ、Task Queue の方を使ったらいいと思います。Task Queue の方はドキュメントがあります。

Comment: Pub/Sub用のライブラリとは何を指していますでしょうか。Pub/Sub ClientLibraryでしょうか。また、Pub/SubはMessagingサービスなので、Pub/SubをTaskQueueの様に使うことは出来ると思いますが、TaskQueueをPub/Subの様に使うことは出来ないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

クライアントライブラリや、REST APIを使用してメッセージのパブリッシュが可能です。

GAE/SEでPub/Subのメッセージをサブスクライブしたい場合、試したことはないですがPull型はGAEの使用上は利用できないと思いますので、Push型のサブスクリプションと対応するエンドポイントを定義すればメッセージの受信も可能になります。

参考

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push